# Add a reference from a directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to write a custom directive that emits a reference to another section but I cannot find any documentation on the available node types or how to pragmatically emit a reference.

## test.rst

```
.. _test:

Test
====

.. test::

The test directive should generate a reference in the form of :ref:`test`.
```

## test.py

```
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('test', TestDirective)
    return {'version': '0.1'}

class TestDirective(Directive):
    def run(self):
        # this would normally come from an argument on the directive
        name = 'test'

        node = nodes.block_quote()
        node += nodes.Text('The ref is: ')

        # this should emit :ref:`name` where name is variable
        # node += ???

        return [node]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
node += nodes.reference(refid=name)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to correctly cross reference, and would be like ``The ref is: `test`_`` which is not the same as ``The ref is: :ref:`test` ``. I was expecting some form of pending_xref, but there seems to be some sort of API to create them so that they get the correct domain, etc. I just can't figure out that API from the source.